How to deduce zoom level from gsd?
I have the following code:
with rasterio.open(image) as dataset:
    transform = dataset.transform
    sizeX = transform[0]

I need to deduce the maximum zoom level for which it makes sense to tile an image.
Can I, and if so, how can I deduce the zoom level from this gsd info?
PS.
I am not an expert in this field.
